# Gray code fifo getting number of elements in buffer

Tags: verilog, counter, fifo

I have 2 different clocks, one for reading and one for writing. I am using gray-code to synchronize the pointers with an additional 2 flip-flops for synchronization on the differnt clock of the input signal.

The articles that I have read indicate how to determine the full and empty signal using gray code by comparing the 2MSB for full state and equality for empty state.

However, I need to get the number of elements in the buffer and not just the full or empty signals. Is this possible to do with gray code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most understandable way to compute the difference between two gray-code values is to synchronize them with a common clock, convert them to binary, and then do an ordinary binary subtraction on them.  While it may be possible to design a fully-combinatorial circuit that would compute the difference between two gray-code values in such a way that if all bits of one particular value are stable, and one bit in the other value changes, only one bit in the output would change and all others would remain stable, such a design would be much more complicated than one which simply synchronizes both counters, converts to binary, and subtracts.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what to use as a commo clock. I only have a read and write clock. Also when you say convert to binary and subtract, how do you handle the rollover case without having too much extra logic since my depth is not a power of 2.

Comment: @Roarer: Whatever circuitry is going to be using the difference will usually be clocked; synchronizing both source and destination gray code counters to that clock will then allow other computations to be done synchronously.  Rounding up to the next power-of-two modulus will make things much easier than using a non-power-of-two modulus., even if you don't need the full depth.

Comment: So lets say the differenc is needed by the read clock. So I would have to insert a registers for the write gray pointer to synchronize them. So the write is delayed by 1 clock cycle compared to the read pointer. Is this what you mean by synchronize the gray code to the other clock domain? (Just an always block running on read clock where i assign the write pointer from the read clock into the write clock?)

Comment: @Roarer: That's the idea, but reliable synchronization requires double register, so the first opportunity to do something with the written data would be on the third clock cycle in the read domain.  If a write occurs happens very near a read clock edge, the first register might latch a metastable condition; if the output of that affected the inputs to multiple registers, some might see the write as having occurred while others might not.  Having the first register feed *only* to the second register in the synchronizer means that everything will either see that the write has occurred, or...

Comment: ...see that it hasn't.  Using a single synchronizer will *usually* work, but may cause occasional weird behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you ask about the common clock and mentioned that your depth is not a power of two.

First : Edit your original post and add that question and the information.

Second: In an a-synchronous FIFO there is no common clock. The write operations are all run from the write clock. The read operations are all run from the read clock. The critical part is to exchange information between the clock domains. That is where the gray code comes in.

Third: An a-synchronous FIFO uses gray code because only one bit changes at a time. Important there is that the process is circular. Thus the difference between your last and your first value also only differs by one bit:

```
Counter   Gray-code
  000       000
  001       001
  010       011
  011       010
  100       110
  101       111
  110       101
  111       100 <-- Last 
  000       000 <-- First again
```

This works if and only if the depth (and thus the counters) are a power of two. Therefore an a-synchronous FIFO **always** has a depth which is a power of two.

If you **must** have a different depth you can add a synchronous FIFO to the beginning or the end. However if you think about it: a FIFO is just an elastic buffer. The behavior if it is e.g. 16 entries deep or 12 entries is not different, other then that you have the potential to store more values.

Last: As supercat said: You convert from binary to Gray code, cross to the other clock domain, then convert Gray code to binary again. 
In the end clock domain you can safely compare read and write counters to determine the fill-level of the FIFO.
If the level is needed on both read and write side you have to implement this process twice, once in each clock domain.

Comment: There are forms of single-bit-change codes which non power-of-two sizes.  For example, a three-bit counter sequence 000-001-011-111-110-100.  Using a power-of-two modulus will make things easier elsewhere, but isn't absolutely essential.

Comment: I know, I contemplated mentioning it, but I did not in the end. So you are right I obfuscated a bit over it. The problem is two fold: 1/ Its is **a lot more** difficult to generate a shorter sequence from a binary counter, especially with 8 or 9 bit counters. 2/ It is only of limited use as you can not use it for an arbitrary depth. e.g. you can not make a 3 sequence gray code.

Comment: It's not hard to generate a single-bit-change counter of any even modulus with the same length as the next power of two.  Divide-by-three could be accommodated by doing divide-by-six and decoding two patterns for each count value.  On the other hand, doing things like modular subtraction for a power-of-two modulus is much cheaper than for a non-power-of-two modulus.